# Using function to transform a list

Tags: programming

I have a list like that: {{Integer,String},....},  integer ranges from 1 to 900 and String "I" to "IV".

And I need to find which pair of {x,y} each sublist is related to, so i can get a new list like that: {{real,real},{real,real},{real,real}....}.

I did the following code:

```
   Fcoord[coord : {_, _}] := (
   If[(Mod[coord[[1]], 30.]) != 0, 
    y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30] + 1)*100;
    x = Mod[coord[[1]], 30.]*100, y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30])*100;
    x = 3000.
    ];
   Which[
       coord[[2]] = "I", x; y, 
       coord[[2]] = "II", x=-1*x,
       coord[[2]] = "III",x = -1*x; y= -1*y, 
       coord[[2]] = "IV", y=-1*y
    ];
   coord[[1]] = x;
   coord[[2]] = y;
   );
```

BUT,  The following error is occurring:

```
Fcoord[{300, "II"}]

Set::setps: {300,II} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Set::setps: {300,II} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Set::setps: {300,II} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

General::stop: Further output of Set::setps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

The purpose is transform, eg., a list : {{242,"I"},{56, "IV"},etc...} , into

{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}, etc...}. Using this code:

```
 Fcoord[#]&/@list.
```

UPDATE 1:

For better understanding:

I have a collection of pairs of cooordinates, ranging from -3000 to 3000,scaled both x-axis and y-axis,that have to fall into grids. So, I created grids of 100 X 100, e.g.: in the first quadrant of cartesian coordinates, there are 900 grids, and I intend  this code identify each grid as a pair of {x,y}. I use as the refference the upper right vertice of a square.

Let´s say that I want to know which coordinates are for the grid number 30, in the second cartesian quadrant, so I did the function Fcoord[...], to point the pairs {x,y} for this {grid number, "cartesian quadrant"}.

Update2:

Another example, I know that grid number 900, "IV" is x= 3000, and y = - 3000, so I want to create a function that you put the grid number and quadrant, and it tells wich coordinate is (remember,that I am using the upper right vertice, but  in the 3rd and 4th quadrant you should considerer the grids 'upside down"

Comment: belisarius ,I did updates.

Comment: on first glance, you are using `=` (assignment) where you mean `==` (equality) ?. by the way it's good that you're trying to go with Mathematica's style. it may take a while, but it will pay off.

Comment: Thanks amr. I tried = and ==,  but the same error happened.

Comment: oh i see. it's because function parameters are "literal" pattern replacements (they aren't really variables), so when you type `coord[[1]] = x` inside, the system sees it as `{300,II} = x` when it is applied. there's ways around this, but i would recommend using `Map` as you are attempting to. `Map` isn't designed to modify the original list, it always gives you a completely new list. lots of $$ goes into making this inefficient-sounding thing efficient, so generally you shouldn't worry about performance with something as basic as `Map`. Also take a look at functions such as `NestList`.

Comment: Here is a version of the code to show a few different things/tricks: `Fcoord[{n_, s_}] := Module[{x, y},
   {y, x} = 100*If[Divisible[n, 30],
      QuotientRemainder[n, 30] + {1, 0},
      {Quotient[n, 30], 30}];
   
   s /. {
     "I" -> {x, y},
     "II" -> {-x, y},
     "III" -> {-x, -y},
     "IV" -> {x, -y}}];

Fcoord /@ {{242, "I"}, {56, "IV"}}` Note that Mathematica has functions for a bunch of stuff, even for things you would normally think are too specialized.

Comment: Amr, mathematica code is fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't followed your logic carefully, but you probably want something like

```
Fcoord[coord : {_?NumericQ, _String}] :=
 Module[{x, y},
  If[(Mod[coord[[1]], 30]) != 0,
   y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30] + 1)*100; x = Mod[coord[[1]], 30]*100,
   y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30])*100; x = 3000.];

  Switch[coord[[2]],
   "I",   { x,  y},
   "II",  {-x,  y},
   "III", {-x, -y},
   "IV",  { x, -y}]
  ]

Fcoord /@ {{242, "I"}, {56, "IV"}}
(* {{200, 900}, {2600, -200}} *)
```

---

**Edit**

Just for fun, this is equivalent to:

```
Fcoord[coord : {_?NumericQ, _String}] :=
 Module[{x, y},
  If[(Mod[coord[[1]], 30]) != 0,
   y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30] + 1)*100; x = Mod[coord[[1]], 30]*100,
   y = (Quotient[coord[[1]], 30])*100; x = 3000.];

  {x, y} Tuples[{1, -1}, 2][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]][[FromDigits[coord[[2]], "Roman"]]]]
```